# Converting list strings to integers

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to converting string lists to integers but it always fails with the same error no matter which method I use to convert.

The error is `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
#list2 = [int(s) for s in list1]
#list2 = map(int, list1)
try:
    for i in list1 :
        list2.append(int(list1));
except :
    print "The int conversion failed"

print list2
```

The initial list, `list1`, just contains some string numbers:

```
[['4183'], ['4034'], ['3342'], ['3482'], ['8567'], ['1052'], ['8135'], ['5561'], ['517'], 
 ['1218'], ['8877']]
```

How can get I avoid the list input error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the problem is that you `list1` contains a **list of list of strings**. Not a **list of strings**.

It depends on what you want.

- If you want a **list of ints**, you can do:

  ```
  [int(x) for line in list1 for x in line]
  ```

  This generates:

  ```
  >>> [int(x) for line in list1 for x in line]
  [4183, 4034, 3342, 3482, 8567, 1052, 8135, 5561, 517, 1218, 8877]
  ```
- If on the other hand, you want a **list of list of ints**, you can work with:

  ```
  [[int(x) for x in line] for line in list1]
  ```

  This generates:

  ```
  >>> [[int(x) for x in line] for line in list1]
  [[4183], [4034], [3342], [3482], [8567], [1052], [8135], [5561], [517], [1218], [8877]]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with a list *of lists* of strings. This should work, for obtaining a list of integers:

```
lst = [['4183'], ['4034'], ['3342'], ['3482'], ['8567'], ['1052'], ['8135'], ['5561'], ['517'], ['1218'], ['8877']]

[int(x[0]) for x in lst]
=> [4183, 4034, 3342, 3482, 8567, 1052, 8135, 5561, 517, 1218, 8877]
```

Or, if you intend to keep the list of lists, but with integers:

```
[[int(x[0])] for x in lst]
=> [[4183], [4034], [3342], [3482], [8567], [1052], [8135], [5561], [517], [1218], [8877]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say that something is, for example, `i = ['3342']`, you're saying it's a list with one string ('3342').

Furthermore, when you use a `for` loop, you should refer to each object in the list as the variable you declared after the `for`:

```
list1 = ['4183', '4034', '3342', '3482', '8567', '1052', '8135', '5561', '517', '1218', '8877']
list2 = []
try:
    for i in list1 :
        list2.append(int(i))
except :
    print("The int conversion failed")

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the inner lists always have length 1:

```
list2 = map(lambda xs: int(xs[0]), list1)
```

For arbitrary length inner lists:

```
from functools import partial
list2 = map(partial(map, int), list1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because you'e trying to convert your whole list into integer. The correct way to do that would be `list2.append(int(i))`. But this also won't work because you have a 2D array and not a simple list. When you loop through your array using `for i in list1`you are getting a list with 1 element on it every iteration.

```
['4183'] # 1st iteration
['4034'] # 2nd iterativo etc...
```

The problem with that is you can't converte a list into an integer directly, even if it have only 1 element on it.

To solve that you could do another for loop for every `i` (very inapropriate approach, but works!). Or you can try to flatten your original list and then your for loop will work (just don't forget to change `list1`to `i`).

Although, I think that the best way to solve your problem, a more "pythonic" approach to this problem would be using the built-in function `map`. And do something like: `map(list1, int)`. In this approach you would also need to flatten your list first.